# JSONP parse error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

Im having troubles with a JSONP call. I have two ways to call it, First way Im getting correct json response, but I cant access the values due callback function was't called. In second call, the callback function is called but the response is truncated. Server is managed by a third party so I will try ask without put their url here.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    crossDomain : true,
    url : "http://94.177.162.128/agent-server-neol/api/matchingFaq/autocomplete?text=Gas&language=es&maxResults=5",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonp : "jsonCallback",
    jsonpCallback : "autocomplete"
});

$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    crossDomain : true,
    url : "http://94.177.162.128/agent-server-neol/api/matchingFaq/autocomplete?text=Gas&language=es&maxResults=5",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonp : "callback",
    jsonpCallback : "autocomplete"
});
```

Any ideas? They give us a example but the example is executing in same server, We have to call it from out so that We work with jsonp.

Thanks

Comment: The question is: Does the server support JSONP? JSONP requires the server to send not only a `jsonstring` as response, but rather something like `functionname(jsonstring)`

Comment: Yes I think so, When I send the callback, response comes with "autocomplete(JSONTRUCATED",

Comment: @user1422434 If the response is truncated then it is obviously server's side fault.

Comment: But only when I send callback method, If I dont, response comes full, If I enter using url direct (not ajax) too the response is full